# getaddrinfo(), I can specify a service without a host, what does it mean?

Tags: networking

`man getaddrinfo`:

```
 int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                       const struct addrinfo *hints,
                       struct addrinfo **res);
```

> Either node or service, but not both, may be NULL.

Specifying `node` only is comprehensible, then it gives you all the available services related to one particular host. But what does it mean if only specify a `service` without a `node/host` ? Scanning all hosts in the Web ?

Answer (score 1):

> Specifying node only is comprehensible, then it gives you all the available services related to one particular host.

Absolutely not. If the service is `NULL`, the returned `addrinfo` structs will have the port/service set to `0`, it will **not** return a struct for each service available on the host.

> But what does it mean if only specify a service without a node/host?

If `AI_PASSIVE` is not specified in `.ai_flags`, it will return the address of the loop device (`127.0.0.1` for ipv4, `::1` for ipv6).

If `AI_PASSIVE` is specified, it will return the  "wildcard" address (`0.0.0.0` for ipv4, `::` for ipv6).

You can read the whole thing in the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html), in the paragraph starting with "If the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is specified ...".

Everything is also clearly stated in the manpage you quote from.